# ¿Como transformar imagen base64 a File?

Tags: javascript, canvas, blob

Estoy generando un canvas dentro de mi aplicación, luego me gustaría subir lo que se cree en ese canvas como una imagen `png` a mi servidor. El problema que estoy teniendo es que se sube, con peso obviamente pero la imagen no se ve.

El canvas queda en base 64

```
var img_b64 = fotoFirmaService.getImagenFirma(); //base64 de la imagen
var png = img_b64.split(',')[1];
var the_file = new Blob([window.atob(png)], { type: 'image/png', encoding: 'utf-8' });
var imagen_firma = new File([the_file], 'imagen_firma.png', { type: 'image/png' });
```

Al imprimir el valor de `imagen_firma` obtengo :

```
File {
    lastModified : 1489088454413
    lastModifiedDate : Thu Mar 09 2017 16:40:54 GMT-0300 (CLT)
    name : "imagen_firma.png"
    size : 16926
    type : "image/png"
    webkitRelativePath : ""
}
```

Sin embargo, la imagen en mi servidor queda vacía. Hago el mismo procedimiento con input tipo file, pero se suben correctamente. Imprimi la estructura de esos archivos y son idénticas a este File pero en este caso no funciona.

**EDIT**

Es con este codigo que subo el archivo a mi servidor :

```
var payload = new FormData();
payload.append('file', imagen_firma);

$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'dsaasas/UploadImage/' + imagen_firma.name,
    data: payload,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
    transformRequest: angular.identity
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
    console.log("bien");
    console.log(response);
}, function errorCallback(response) {
    console.log(response);
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
});
```

Y este es mi codigo C#, esta con WCF

```
public string UploadImage(string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpPostedFile file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];
            if (file == null)
                return null;
            string targetFilePath = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"] + fileName;
            file.SaveAs(targetFilePath);
            return "succ   " + file.FileName.ToString();

            //return fileName;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message + " - " + ex.InnerException;

        }
    }
```

Comment: qué lenguaje tienes en el lado del cliente, y cómo mandas la petición al servidor?

Comment: en el lado de cliente estoy con javascript, ahora actualizo el codigo de como envio al servidor el archivo.

Comment: olvidé preguntarte, qué lenguaje usas al lado del server, y por qué transformar el archivo a base64 y de ahí a un blob para construir un archivo que posteriormente será agregado en el FormData como file para enviarlo al server?

Comment: estoy utilizando c# en el lado del servidor. La verdad es que lo que necesito es que ese string en base64 que es una imagen, transformarlo a un File para subirlo al servidor. Quizas no sea la manera correcta de hacerlo y es por eso que acude a la comunidad a ver si me podian echar una mano

Comment: ya te entendí <meme de squirtle> vamo a responder </meme de squirtle> :D 
 
C# con ASPnet MVC o webforms?

Comment: ajajajaja @fredyfx espero esa respuesta!

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55088/discussion-between-sioesi-and-fredyfx).

Comment: Tengo una duda: El servicio `fotoFirmaService.getImagenFirma()`, ¿es lo mismo que hacer `canvas.toDataURL()`?

Comment: exacto, estoy trabajando con Angular y el canvas esta en otra vista, por eso cree un servicio que guarde el valor del canvas y desde otras vistas puedo acceder a ese valor

Comment: Cuando dices "queda vacía", ¿te refieres a que la imagen no tiene ningún peso? Pon un breakpoint en tu código C# para que veas el instante en que la imagen es recibida y analices su contenido.

Comment: Si llega con peso, pero se ve blanca, no es la imagen correcta

Answer (score 9, accepted):

He encontrado 2 posibles soluciones:

- Corregir el código binario que es pasado al `Blob`:

  Ejemplo:

  ```
  function fixBinary (bin) {
    var length = bin.length;
    var buf = new ArrayBuffer(length);
    var arr = new Uint8Array(buf);
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      arr[i] = bin.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return buf;
  }

  var img_b64 = fotoFirmaService.getImagenFirma(); //base64 de la imagen
  var png = img_b64.split(',')[1];
  var binary = fixBinary(window.atob(png));// <-- Usamos la fn "fixBinary"
  var the_file = new Blob([binary], {type: 'image/png'});// <-- Sacamos el encode
  var imagen_firma = new File([the_file], 'imagen_firma.png', { type: 'image/png' });
  ```

  Fuente: [`SOen - encode/decode image with base64 breaks image`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14967647/encode-decode-image-with-base64-breaks-image)
- Usar [`canvas.toBlob()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) (ver `Polyfill`)

  Ejemplo:

  ```
  /// Service fotoFirmaService

  // Creamos un nuevo método en servicio "fotoFirmaService"
  // el cual devolverá directamente el Blob
  getImagenFirmaBlob: function(format, quality) {
    var response;
    // "canvas" debe ser un "HTMLCanvasElement"
    canvas.toBlob(function(blob){
      response = blob;
    }, format, quality);
    return response;
  }

  /// Controller

  // Usando el nuevo método "getImagenFirmaBlob"
  var the_file = fotoFirmaService.getImagenFirmaBlob("image/png"); //blob de la imagen
  var imagen_firma = new File([the_file], 'imagen_firma.png');
  ```

Comment: la segunda opcion me ayudo! Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: @sioesi, si miras en detalle, el método `toBlob` es prácticamente la primer solución, con la diferencia que eventualmente puede llegar a ser `nativo`.

Comment: Me fui directamente a la segunda, porque habia intentado algo muy similar pero de m ala forma, con est se soluciono mi problema!

Comment: ahora sí hermano @Sioesi ! a seguir con todo el power 2.0! gracias @MarcosGallardo!

Comment: saludos amigo @fredyfx!

Comment: me alegra que hayan dado respuesta a la pregunta @sioesi :D

Answer (score 6):

Tambien aplique otra solución que trabajo bien para mi :

```
var blob = dataURItoBlob(fotoFirmaService.getImagenFirma());
var imagen_firma = new File([blob], 'imagen_firma.jpg', { type: 'image/jpg' });
```

Y la funcion `dataURItoBlob` :

```
function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
    // convert base64/URLEncoded data component to raw binary data held in a string
    var byteString;
    if (dataURI.split(',')[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0)
        byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    else
        byteString = unescape(dataURI.split(',')[1]);

    // separate out the mime component
    var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];

    // write the bytes of the string to a typed array
    var ia = new Uint8Array(byteString.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    return new Blob([ia], { type: mimeString });
}
```

Comment: como hago que se muestre la imagen resultante en un html?